# Android GCM successfully registers in both emulator and device but receives only on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

Emulator uses Google API image 4.3

Device has Android 4.0.3

As said, the app successfully registers on both systems but receives only on the emulator.
The server sends the same notification to both systems in the same call to GCM servers, which respond correctly to all the devices specified.

The devices (that have the same app and google account configured) are connected to the same lan. The emulator receives the message, the device doesn't.

Here the code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<receiver
    android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.remote.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="it.uniroma1.informatica.didapp.remote.GCMIntentService" />
```

GCMIntentService.java

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
public GCMIntentService() {
    super(GCMIntentService.class.getName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm         = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String               messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    Bundle               extras      = intent.getExtras();

    if(!extras.isEmpty()) {
               if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
        } else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
        } else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification();
        }
    }

    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    Log.v("GCM", "HANDLED");
}
```

GCMBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    Log.v("GCM", "RECEIVED");
}
}
```